# Normality test without knowing a sample's mean

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, normality-assumption, confirmatory-factor

I've been searching for a way to approach my problem.

This is a scenario from a Multivariate Statistics Assignment on Confirmatory Factor Analysis.

We've been given only a **correlation matrix on 6 variables, the Standard Deviations and sample size**. The model assumes that $X1$, $X2$ and $X$3 are indicators of given Factor $F1$, while $X4$, $X5$ and $X6$ are indicators of another Factor $F2$ (we actually know which factors and variables those are, but since my question is theoretical, I am keeping this simpler).

I've already evaluated the measurement model, found it has 7 degrees of freedom and moved on to the method's assumptions.

Now, assuming I want to do the Factor Extraction step using the ML estimator, which assumes data normality: is there any way I can test for my sample normality with the provided information?

I appreciate any small insights and/or directions that may help!

Comment: Re the title: adding in information about the means wouldn't help at all; you still have nothing concrete about the shape of the joint distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot test for normality only knowing the first two moments of a distribution (correlation, covariance, mean, and SDs are all first-and-second including product moment estimators). You need to know the entire sample to test for goodness of fit for a particular distribution. At the very least, you would need to know skewness and kurtosis to exclude some specific violations of normality.

Comment: thank you for the input